# Why there are no colors in the html or css code text in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I code in Visual Studio, it doesn't show any colours in the code text. It shows blue and green colours only for the class and comments texts. Also, VS doesn't suggest me anything when I code. Apart from this, everything things run fine and if there are any errors it shows up in the problem section.

[image]

I try to change theme color but its not work

Comment: You can try installing new themes, linking an article I found online.
https://www.spec-india.com/blog/vscode-themes

Comment: Also you can look into this issue this may help: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20347

Comment: Open the `Change Language Mode` menu with `Ctrl+K M` shortcut and make sure HTML is selected

Comment: If you have any errors in that file it won't be able to parse it and apply semantic colors.

Comment: no, its completely works